# Rails editing migration to ignore an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an app with posts, users, tags and such. I've been working on it locally and have not been able to push it to heroku because of an issue. In the end, I succeeded in pushing my app to heroku, then realised that I never migrated my database there. So I ran

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and got this error:

```
== 20141116151429 CreatePosts: migrating ======================================
-- drop_table(:posts)
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "posts" does not exist
: DROP TABLE "posts"
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "posts" does not exist
```

I looked up the migration and for some reason, it had the drop tables line before anything else:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :posts
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title,              null: false, default: ""
      t.text :description, null: false, default: ""

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I commented out the drop table line, even deleted it and then commit it using git commit, then tried to run heroku rake db:migrate, but the error still shows. I know this is a serious muck up, but I don't know what to do from here.

I have not tried resetting the databse for fear of what might go wrong, although I can, technically, lose the posts/users/comments and such I have created so far.

Is there a way I can remedy this and still push all my database data to heroku? If not, what should I do to get the app running in the first place?

EDIT:

I even changed the migration to be:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title,              null: false, default: ""
      t.text :description, null: false, default: ""

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :posts
  end
end
```

But the error still shows. I don't understand: I know I edited the right file (20141116151429_create_posts.rb) and I REMOVED that line. Even changed the entire contents of it and commit these changes, but running heroku rake db:migrate still comes up with the drop_tables error.

From what I understand, isn't heroku rake db:migrate pretty much the same as rake db:migrate? If so, then it should run the migrations that are pending. In this case, all of them are, as I've never migrated to heroku. If so, then any change I make to a migration file that hasnt been run should be reflected. And yet I am getting this error.

Comment: Can't you do def down and do drop_table.

Comment: Comment #drop_table :posts and migrate, It will work...

Comment: I did comment out drop_table - seemed to be the most logical reaction. I even deleted that line and ran the migration, but the error still shows.

Comment: Okay re-name def name as "def up" and comment #drop_table :posts, now try....

Comment: I tried changing the entire structure to the edit above - it still says -- drop_table(:posts) ...

I'm just shocked about why it's insisting that the line is there when I removed it. Any ideas? (Thank you for the quick replies, by the way.)

Comment: Did you tried commenting you def down and migrated?

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you comment out the drop_table syntax. But if it does not working then try to use below syntax.

It will run `drop_table` only when table exist in database.

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table 'posts' if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'posts'
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title,              null: false, default: ""
      t.text :description, null: false, default: ""

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is embarassing.

Thank you @Dipak and @RubyOnRails for your quick replies.

It seems that my commits were ignoring the migration file completely after the first commit. I reverted back and made a clean commit with the added changes and it made the migrations without any issues.

Perhaps my commits to heroku after the first one did not go through.

Embarassing.

Answer (score 0):

if you use 'change', drop line is useless

```
 # == Reversible Migrations
  #
  # Starting with Rails 3.1, you will be able to define reversible migrations.
  # Reversible migrations are migrations that know how to go +down+ for you.
  # You simply supply the +up+ logic, and the Migration system will figure out
  # how to execute the down commands for you.
  #
  # To define a reversible migration, define the +change+ method in your
  # migration like this:
  #
  #   class TenderloveMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  #     def change
  #       create_table(:horses) do |t|
  #         t.column :content, :text
  #         t.column :remind_at, :datetime
  #       end
  #     end
  #   end
  #
   class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :posts do |t|
          t.string :title,              null: false, default: ""
          t.text :description, null: false, default: ""

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```